# How do I connect a Unity game to a database server?

Tags: c#, sql, unity-game-engine

So I have a project I'm working on that involves connecting a game to a centralized database (for leaderboards, user accounts, etc.) The game is on Unity 3d for PC (it won't be a web game), and I have generated an SQL script for the database that could either be installed on a dedicated local server, or a remote server. My question is this: how do I seamlessly query that database from within the Unity game, whether I'm accessing data in the database, or updating high scores, or the like?

Answer (score 1):

Direct connection from unity to SQL server is bad approach regarding on security issues. You have to build [web service](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_service) to handle communication between unity and database. In case you want to query database from C#, most common way is to use [ADO](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dw70f090(v=vs.110).aspx). But i doubt ADO is going to work with MONO. So best approach in this case would be to use [SQLite](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/database-access/providers/sqlite/) database.